# Как конвертировать curl запрос в http Flutter запрос?

Tags: http, curl, flutter, dart

Сейчас я работаю с одним REST API для своего мобильного приложения и я не могу правильно отправить запрос. На сайте API есть curl запрос:

```
curl
-u <YOUR_CLIENT_ID>:<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>
-d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=basic"
-X POST https://oauth.fatsecret.com/connect/token
```

> Вот мой код который я использую, чтобы получить ответ:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> ouathTwo() async {
var url = 'https://oauth.fatsecret.com/connect/token';
var body = json.encode({
  'user': clientID,
  'password': clientSecret,
});

print('Body: $body');
var response = await http.post(
  url,
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'scope' : 'basic'
  },
  body: body,
);
print(json.decode(response.body));
return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

Буду признателен, если сможете чем-то помочь:)

Comment: А что именно не работает? Где ошибка? В чем проблема?

Comment: Там проблема в том что он выдаёт ошибку: [invalid request]

Answer (score 1):

1. `-d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=basic"` это `-d или data`, а вы в `headers` засовываете. По этому и выходит `[invalid request]`.
2. Вы навряд ли сможете получить желаемый результат с помощью `http`, так как OAuth это стандарт. И для этого стандарта уже [реализован плагин для взаимодействия с ним](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2) и работать следует с помощью него. Но если вдруг захотите сделать что-то свое, вот вам [спецификации](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

OAuth — открытый протокол (схема) авторизации, который позволяет предоставить третьей стороне ограниченный доступ к защищённым ресурсам пользователя без необходимости передавать ей (третьей стороне) логин и пароль. OAuth поддерживает два метода аутентификации сообщений от клиента: HMAC-SHA1 и RSA-SHA1. Есть возможность передавать сообщения без подписи, тогда в поле типа подписи указывается «plain text». Но в этом случае, согласно спецификации, соединение между клиентом и сервером должно устанавливаться через протокол SSL или TLS.